# Linear Transformation with Change of Basis Question

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

Let $T: \mathbb{R}^5 \rightarrow P_2(\mathbb{R})$ be a linear transformation that has the matrix $$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3 & 2 & 0 & -1 \\ 2 & 6 & 4 & 6&4 \\ 1& 3 & 2 & 2&1 \end{pmatrix}$$ relative to the bases ${(1, 1, 1, 1, 1),(1, 1, 1, 1, 0),(1, 1, 0, 0, 0),(1, 0, 0, 0, 0),(0, 0, 0, 1, 0)}$ of $\mathbb{R}^5$ and ${(1 + x + x^2
, x, 1)}$ of $P_2(R)$

Find $Ker(T)$ and find $Im(T)$

I know the steps to find kernel and image, but i'm not sure how to first make the matrix with respect to the two bases, please help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $$\alpha = \left\lbrace \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 0 \\ 0\\ 0\\ 0
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix} \right\}.$$
Let $\beta = \{1 + x + x^2,x,1 \} \subset P_2(\Bbb R)$.  Then $$[T]_\alpha^\beta = A = \begin{bmatrix}
1&3&2&0&-1\\
2&6&4&6&4\\
1&3&2&2&1
\end{bmatrix}.$$
Row reducing, you can find that $$\text{null} A = \text{span} \left\{ \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ -1 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix}
, \begin{bmatrix}
-2\\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
-3\\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}
\right\};$$
$$\text{col}(A) = \text{span} \left\{ \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 6 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix} \right\}. $$
So the image of $T$ is spanned by the vectors 
$$\beta_1 + 2\beta_2 + \beta_3 = x^2+3x+2  \ \ \text{ and }\ \  6\beta_2 + 2\beta_3 = 6x + 2. $$
There is a trick to convert your $\text{null}(A)$ into your desired $\ker(T)$. (We could have applied a similar trick to find the image of $T$.) Take the column space of the following matrix.
$$[I]_\alpha \begin{bmatrix} 
1 & -2 & -3 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 0\\ 
-1 & 0 & 0\\ 
1& 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & -2 & -3 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 0\\ 
-1 & 0 & 0\\ 
1& 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0&-1&-2\\
1&-1&-2\\
1&-2&-2\\
2&-2&-2\\
1&-2&-3
\end{bmatrix}.$$
See if you can work out why this is correct.